# Error message alignment for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Need to fix the validation error for the radio button

For Eg: radio button - upload  and radio button - Embedded

In that, error message is coming in between the radio button and content upload. But I don't want that, Actually I need error message should come in after the content upload.

How do I fix this

```
    <form class="admin_forms" id="video_form" action="" method="post">
   <div class="hv_details row-fluid">
     <div class="span2">Select Video Type<span class="star">*</span></div>
     <label class="checkbox">
     <input id="radio_1" type="radio" name="radio_group_1" value="upload">
      Upload a Video</input></label>
       <label class="checkbox">
       <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio_group_1" value="embed">
      Youtube embeded code</input>
        </label>
        </div>
      </form>

 <script>
   $("#video_form").validate({

           rules: { 
             radio_group_1:"required",
          },
           message:{
            radio_group_1:"Please Select Video Type",
          }


 </script>
```

And I try position:absolute but for the responsive site it fixed in the position and not as responsive.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Give some code for help you.

Comment: Please put your code as well with your question

Comment: @Lal and Ronak Code is added

Answer (score 0):

You can use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) for that.

Example:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#main p').appendTo('#main .inner');
```

This will shift the `p` to inner div.

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="inner"><p>Hello</p></div>
</div>
```